# Trying to find common character between two strings and display it console

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string str1="fire";
            string str2 = "fire";
            foreach(char obj in str1)
                if(obj.ToString().Contains(str2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }

}
```

Here 'obj' will look into the 'str2' but will not take the common characters. That is obj each time checks if any common character exists in str2 but though there, will not display common match characters.

Comment: You are checking if a character contains a string. Like looking for a haystack in a needle.

Comment: Your logic is backwards; right now you're asking if a single char contains a multi-char string.

Comment: Why do you use a char object(every single letter) to search the whole string?

Answer (score 4):

Just another solution.. although probably just as bad performance wise.. but smaller:

```
var str1 = "fire";
var str2 = "hire";

var common = str1.Intersect(str2);

foreach (var c in common)
    Console.WriteLine(c); // "i", "r", "e"
```

Comment: I don't think this has bad performance compared to other solution in which in fact we still need 2 nested for-loop (the inner one is implemented by `Contains`), the only problem with this is only distinct characters are printed, for example the OP may want `firer` and `hirer` should output `i, r, e, r` but using `Intersect` will output only `i, r, e`. But it's still confusing on what actually the OP wants. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :**  you are checking the `character` instead of `String`.

**Solution:** you need to check inside a `String` whether it contains the given `Character` or not.

Replace this:

```
 if(obj.ToString().Contains(str2))
```

with this:

```
 if(str2.Contains(obj.ToString()))
```

**Complete SOlution:**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string str1="fire";
            string str2 = "fire";
            foreach(char obj in str1)
            if(str2.Contains(obj.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: +1. Note that this solution should not be used for code that requires any reasonable performance due to multiple linear searches.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int commonCharacterCount(string s1, string s2)
    {
        int common = 0;
        string toIterate = string.Empty;
        if (s1.Length > s2.Length)
            toIterate = s1;
        else
        {
            toIterate = s2;
            s2 = s1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < toIterate.Length; j++)
            {
                if (s1[i] == toIterate[j])
                {
                    toIterate = toIterate.Remove(j, 1);
                    common++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return common;
    }
```

Comment: It would help the OP if you added some description about what your proposed answer does and how it differs from what code they have. It would give them some context and understanding as opposed to just a potential cut and paste answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string str1 = "fire";
            string str2 = "hire ";
            int count = 0;
            foreach (char obj in str1)
                if (str2.Contains(obj.ToString()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(obj);
                    count++;
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```